# Keyboard/mouse shortcut for Inserting signature in Outlook 2003?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2003, email-signature

Is there a quick keyboard or mouse shortcut to insert your signature in a reply email in Outlook 2003 SP3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process I used (thanks to Par for the good link):

**Pre-2007**

> 1. Add your signature to AutoText
> 2. Compose and email, filling in the header fields,
>      so your cursor is in the body
> 3. Right-click the toolbar and choose Customize
> 4. Choose Autotext, then the name of your signature
> 5. Then drag (the name) to one of your toolbars
> 6. Rename the name with an '&' in front of the letter
>      that you want to be the shortcut key
> 7. You can now click on the signature button in the toolbar,
>      or use ALT-chosenkey to insert your signature.

Note that it appears to not be possible (without an addin) to make a keyboard shortcut  for your signature in Outlook 2010.

Comment: Think you might have meant to click the quote toolbar item when you clicked code. Code makes everything monospace and adds syntax coloring.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at **AutoHotkey** and [PhraseExpress](http://www.phraseexpress.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there is one. [Here's](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/assistance/HP030842231033.aspx) Microsofts own list over the shortcuts that are available.

[Here's](http://blogs.msdn.com/jonathanh/archive/2004/05/01/creating-your-own-keyboard-shortcuts-in-outlook.aspx) a blog post about how to create your own shortcut that might help you.

Comment: +1 for the link it led to figuring out how to do it.